# JavaScript RegEx expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to compose an expression that will allow any number or decimal point, but only one decimal.

Allowed formats would be

`100.00, 100`

but not

```
'100d.00, a100, -100, 100.000.000.00'
```

For that goal, so far I have this:

```
/[^0-9$.]/g
```

Comment: Try searching [decimal regex javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decimal+regex+javascript).

Comment: In your example you have two decimal but you say only one decimal allowed

Answer (score 0):

I think `/^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/` should work. If you need more than two digits after the decimal point `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

This is one or more digits followed optionally by a decimal and one or more digits.  The `^` and `$` mean that it *must* match exactly this in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.  It looks for a number 1 through 9 one or more times, followed by 0 to 9 zero or more times, followed by a decimal 0 or 1 time, and then 0-9 0 or more times.

```
/^[1-9]+[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, how about

`/\d*\.?\d*/g`

that would collect zero or more digits (\d*) followed by a possible decimal point (.?) followed by possibly zero or more digits (\d*)

hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of numbers in a string like `100d.00, a100, -100, 1,000, 100.000.000.00, 100.00, 1000.00. , 100` then you can use `/(?:^| )(-?\d+\.?\d+)(?:$|,|. )/` to get the ones you need. It finds numbers either following a space or the start of the string with only one decimal place in them. The tricky bit is that you may need to adjust the `(?:$|,|. )` part. It makes sure your number ends with the end of string, a comma, or if it was in a sentence it would end with a period and a space.

When you're running the test against these numbers, what format are they in? Are they each in individual string or are they in a comma delimited string or some arbitrary blob of text? In many cases it may be easier to use the function `isNaN(myString)`.

Comment: It's in a single field, not a sentence. I'll give this a try.

Comment: If it's a single field, try isNan or shorten my regex to `^-?\d+(?:\.?\d*)$`. Explosion Pills' regex ought to work as well but will capture the decimal as an additional field, which is wonky.